# Sed Command to delete specific items in a file

Tags: linux, sed, grep

Probably similar questions have been asked before, but I cant find solution to this one:

The file in which I need to delete strings is :

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
pam_ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
awx ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
***f10222 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
mn2345zp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
ab1235xy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL***
```

<sup>Note: The `***` are to indicate the part I want to delete...the `***` do not really exist in the file.</sup>

I just want to delete these kind of strings marked in bold (or between ***) on multiple files, considering this file as one of them.

What could the sed possibly be for these kind of strings? to delete it and have only the remaining content:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
pam_ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
awx ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I am a newbie with these commands, My try on it: 
On my script I tried adding

```
sed '/[a-z0-9]/d' $user
```

where user contains list of the items between the ***
but it only shows

*sed: can't read : No such file or directory*

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their own efforts in their posts, so kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: why are the other lines not deleted? what distinguishes them from the ones that you do want to remove?

Comment: Maybe `sed '/^\*\*\*/,/\*\*\*$/d'` but that doesn't handle cases where `***` is in the middle of the line, or where the start and end are on the same line.  Does that matter?

Comment: @stevesliva I'm pretty sure the file doesn't actually contain literal `***` strings.  The OP is just using those asterisks as markers to identify the span of lines that he wants to delete from his example file.

Comment: @ottomeister yes exactly the *** are not in the file....I just added it to indicate the part i want to delete. you are right.

Comment: What's your logic/pattern in removing these lines? Do you want to remove last 3 lines, or lines containing some pattern? How can you tell what to remove?

Comment: @kenorb I can't figure out exactly what pattern can I use to delete enitre lines containing the user ID's as its of varied types... its not specific to last N lines... so I need a logic to delete such a thing...

Comment: @Interested-Learner But what's your human logic, can you explain it. Why `awx` line was excluded, what's so special about this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk '$1 ~ /[a-zA-Z]/ && $1 !~ /[0-9]/' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: I get an error:                                                                                                                     awk: fatal: cannot open file `awx' for reading (No such file or directory)                                                              
I am ok with sed or awk to get them deleted somehow... I am using the right file for sure

Comment: @Interested-Learner, I doubt that you are using correct file, or you are in some other directory where file is not present?

Comment: you were right, I think i managed to find the right path. Thanks a lot, but I still need this to be deleted directly in the file, instead it shows the cat of this command as a result of the script and not on the file...

Comment: @Interested-Learner, check my solution now it will save output into Input_file itself and let me know then.

Comment: yes its working great! thanks a lot @RavinderSingh13 !!                                                                                       just a final doubt...what if I have to remove the line " awx ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL " how will the regex change to remove that line as well?

Comment: @Interested-Learner, If you are looking for removing `awx` line then try following `awk '$1 ~ /[a-zA-Z]/ && $1 !~ /[0-9]/ && $1 !~ /awx/' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file` and lemme know?

Comment: it looks like it would work but awx is just for this file, it could be any username without a numerical regex. So in that case how do I delete such regex which sometimes have a number and sometimes just alphabets and symbols?

Answer (score 1):

just try this..

```
  sed '/\*\*\*/,/\*\*\*/d' inputfile
```

it will delete everything between these two pattern even including this patterns also and it can handle that cases also where *** is in the middle of the line.

Comment: sorry my query was not very clear i think...the *** are to indicate the part I want to delete...the *** do not really exist in the file.....

Answer (score 0):

Considering the case the `***` appears in the middle of the line, there may be several options depending on the characteristics of the
input file.

If each file has no more than one enclosed block, please try:

```
sed -i '
:l      ;# defines a label
N       ;# reads the next line and appends it to the pattern space
$!bl    ;# goes back to the label until the EOF
s/\*\*\*.*\*\*\*//      ;# removes the block between *** and ***
s/\n$//                 ;# removes a trailing newline if any
' input.txt
```

If any of the files may contain multiple blocks to be removed,
the `sed` command above does not work as expected due to
the `greedy (longest) match`.
In that case a workaround will be to use `Perl` whose regex supports the
`non-greedy match`:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*\n?//sg' input.txt
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry my query was not very clear i think...the *** are to indicate the part I want to delete...the *** do not really exist in the file.....